# How to create counter on button?

Tags: android, button, textview

I want to create button with text = "SomeText" on center of this button and "0" on right part of button. Where "0" is the Counter and when I click this button  Counter++ increments, and becomes "1"...
I would like to know how to tie textviev with "right part of button" ?

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_menu"
    android:onClick="but1_Count"
    android:text="SomeText"
    android:textColor="@drawable/text_color"
    android:textSize="100dp" />
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> private static int counter = 0;
>
> button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
>     @Override
>     onClick(View v){
>        counter += 1
>        button.setText("Some text" + counter);
>     }
>  });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options.

Create a static variable:

```
private static int buttonClickCount = 0;

public void but1_Count(View v){
    buttonClickCount++;
    v.settext("Clicked " + buttonClickCount);
}
```

Create custom button by extending base button class and implement onClickListener:

```
public class MyButton extends Button implements View.OnClickListener {
    private int counter = 0;
    public MyButton(...){
        this.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        counter++;
        v.setText("Clicked"+counter);
    }
}
```

Extract value from clicked button, parse it as int, and increment:

```
public void but1_count(View v){
    int curr = Integer.parseInt(v.getText().toString());
    v.setText(""+curr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some Text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="button_text">Some Text  %1d</string>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    private Button btnCounter;
    private int count;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnCounter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCounter);

        btnCounter.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.button_text),count));

        btnCounter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count++;
                btnCounter.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.button_text),count));
            }
        });
    }

}
```